# Track iframe embeds of you webpage in GA

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics

I have a simple webpage that hosts a WebGL visualization ( http://blocks.wizb.it ), I've included basic Google Analytics (the normal snippet) for it.

Everything worked great, but now other people are embedding my visualization in an iframe on their own website ( http://bitcoinvox.com/technology/mining/ ). I don't mind this at all at the moment however when I visit their page the visit does not show up under Google Analytics. In all other SO questions regarding this topic people have access to the host page, which I do not have.

Is it possible to track these visits at all? Ideally I want to see where the iframe is embedded (url) as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
function trackMyPage(){
  if(window.top.location !== window.location){
   return window.top.location.href;  //tracked url
  }
}
```

Also you can yse other form to avoid some sites protection:

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zwa64/7/)

Comment: Ok so this allows me to detect being loaded in an iframe. However I don't want block it, I want to track it.

Comment: window.top.location - shows in what domain your page is embedded.

$(document).html - it's for example. Replace it with your tracking code.

Comment: thanks! I'll experiment with adding this to the GA snippet for a bit. When I figure it out will mark this as accepted.